# Python: Closing a for loop by reading stdout

Tags: python, while-loop

```
import os

dictionaryfile = "/root/john.txt"
pgpencryptedfile = "helloworld.txt.gpg"

array = open(dictionaryfile).readlines()


for x in array:
    x = x.rstrip('\n')
    newstring = "echo " + x + " | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 " + pgpencryptedfile
    os.popen(newstring)
```

I need to create something inside the for loop that will read gpg's output. When gpg outputs this string `gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected`, I need the loop to close and print Success!

How can I do this, and what is the reasoning behind it?

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: You're using a `for` loop, not a `while` loop.

Comment: You should look into using `subprocess.Popen` instead of the now deprecated `os.popen`

Comment: Also, does `gpg` write that to `stderr` or `stdout`?

Comment: Can I use the same string concatenation for subprocess.Popen?

Comment: Have you considered using pygpgme to handle the decryption rather than directly calling gpg?

Answer (score 1):

Use [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to call `gpg` and break the loop based on its output.

Something like this (untested since I don't know anything about `gpg`):

```
import subprocess

dictionaryfile = "/root/john.txt"
pgpencryptedfile = "helloworld.txt.gpg"

with open(dictionaryfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x = line.rstrip('\n')
        cmd = ["echo " + x + " | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 " + pgpencryptedfile]
        output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
        if 'gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected' in output:
            break
```

Comment: I'll be running this on Linux so I don't know if cmd does the same thing for both operating systems.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decrypter2.py", line 12, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'check_output'

Comment: That's the error I'm getting now. Sorry if I sound stupid, I'm very new to programming and even newer to python.

Comment: (You don't, but no worries anyway.) Hmm, that seems to say that `check_output` is not defined in `subprocess`. But it is... Try opening an interpreter and running `import subprocess` then `subprocess.check_output(['ls'])` and see if that gives you the same error.

Comment: @user1732102 -- `subprocess.check_output` was added in python version 2.7.  If you're working with an older version, that would explain why you don't have it.

Comment: I installed python2.7.3. After running the script then, I got this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decrypter2.py", line 12, in <module>
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 537, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Dumb question: do `/root/john.txt` and `helloworld.txt.gpg` actually exist in those locations?

Comment: Yes sir. Both those files exist where they are.

Comment: I think the code that you came up with is going to work the best, I just don't know what all these errors I'm getting are from.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what's going on just from the error message then... Can you post small example files in your question for me to try out? (Also, I just changed the `open` call a bit, but it shouldn't make a difference.)

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess


def check_file(dictfile, pgpfile):
    # Command to run, constructed as a list to prevent shell-escaping accidents
    cmd = ["gpg", "--passphrase-fd", "0", pgpfile]

    # Launch process, with stdin/stdout wired up to `p.stdout` and `p.stdin`
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

    # Read dictfile, and send contents to stdin
    passphrase = open(dictfile).read()
    p.stdin.write(passphrase)

    # Read stdout and check for message
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    for line in stdout.splitlines():
        if line.strip() == "gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected":
            # Relevant line was found
            return True

    # Line not found
    return False
```

Then to use:

```
not_integrity_protected = check_file("/root/john.txt", "helloworld.txt.gpg")
if not_integrity_protected:
    print "Success!"
```

If the "gpg: WARNING:" message is actually on `stderr` (which I would suspect it is), change the `subprocess.Popen` line to this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

..and the for loop from `stdout` to `stderr`, like this:

```
for line in stderr.splitlines():
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module which allows you to use:

```
subprocess.call(args, *, stdin, stdout, stderr, shell)
```

(See the [Python Documentation](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html) for how to use the parameters.)

This is good because you can easily read in the exit code of whatever program you call.

For example if you change 'newstring' to:

```
"echo " + x + " | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 " + pgpencryptedfile | grep 'gpg: WARNING: message was not integrity protected'
```

grep will then return 0 if there is a match and a 1 if not matches are found. ([Source](http://ss64.com/bash/grep.html))

This exit code from grep will be returned from the subprocess.call() function and you can easily store it in a variable and use an if statement.

Edit: As Matthew Adams mentions below, you could also read the exit code of gpg itself.

Comment: Oops I just copied that out of the python documentation. I'll fix that.

Comment: How would the subprocess.call line look after I change 'newstring'?

Comment: You don't need all the parameters. I think: 'subprocess.call(newstring, shell=True)' is all you would need.